# AWS : Passing Job parameters Value to Glue job from Step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I have created 3 Glue jobs which have one of Job Parameters key/value like this: runid id

If I execute Glue job using AWS CLI like this, it is working fine:
aws glue start-job-run --jobname $job --arguments='--runid="Runid_10"'

These 3 Glue jobs are inside one step function and state machine Definition is :

```
{
  "Comment":"Sample Step Function",
  "StartAt":"First Glue Job",
  "States": {
      "First Glue Job":{
         "Type": "Task",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
         "Parameters": {
            "JobName": "GlueJob-Firstjob"
      },
      "Next": "Second Glue Job"
    },
    "Second Glue Job":{
         "Type": "Task",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
         "Parameters": {
            "JobName": "GlueJob-Secondjob"
      },
      "Next": "Third Glue Job"
    },
    "Third Glue Job":{
         "Type": "Task",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
         "Parameters": {
            "JobName": "GlueJob-Thirdjob"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

If I am try to execute this State machine with Input parameter, this input parameter value is not passing to Gluejob.
Do I need to modify State machine job definition to pass input parameter value to Glue job which has passed as part of state machine run. Please guide me how to do it.

aws stepfunctions start-execution --state-machine-arn arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:stateMachine:HelloWorld --input "{runid":"Runid_10"}

State Machine is executing successfully but Runid value is not passing to Gluejob Parameters.

Please let me know how to pass Glue job parameters value which has inside state machine Definition.

---

I am using Arguments parameter like this:

```
{
  "Comment":"Sample Step Function",
  "StartAt":"First Glue Job",
  "States": {
      "First Glue Job":{
         "Type": "Task",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
         "Parameters": {
            "JobName": "GlueJob-Firstjob",
            "Arguments": {
                  "--runid":"$.runid"
                }
      },
      "ResultPath" : "$.runid",
      "Next": "Second Glue Job"
    },
    "Second Glue Job":{
         "Type": "Task",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
         "Parameters": {
            "JobName": "GlueJob-Secondjob",
            "Arguments": {
                  "--runid":"$.runid"
                }
      },
      "ResultPath" : "$.runid",
      "Next": "Third Glue Job"
    },
    "Third Glue Job":{
         "Type": "Task",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
         "Parameters": {
            "JobName": "GlueJob-Thirdjob",
            "Arguments": {
                  "--runid":"$.runid"
                }
      },
      "ResultPath" : "$.runid",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Passing Input JSON {"--runid" : "runid_10"} in Input-optional window during execution of "start execution" state machine.

Please Note : runid_n , where n is integer and will change.

I will append runid_10 value to the output file in Glue job and output file is like GlueJob-Firstjob_output_runid_10.csv

Comment: You will have to pass --run_id parameter within the Parameters section of your job. It's not gonna take by itself. It would be like `"--run_id" : $.runid` within the Parameters of glue job

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Trying to add this parameter inside parameters section after glue job name but it is not working. Seems something wrong from my end.

Comment: Hi I'm setting up the stepfunction to run a Glue job, if I run this glue job outside of stepfunction, it will succeed, but if I kickoff the statemachine, the glue job will fail. I have a question here could you take a look please? I suspect there might be some incorrect settings in the permissions or something: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135124/glue-job-succeeded-without-stepfunction-but-failed-if-its-kicked-off-by-stepfu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add it inside `Arguments` within `Parameters` attribute so it will be like:

```
"Parameters" : {
           "JobName": "GlueJob-Firstjob",
           "Arguments": {
                  "--run_id":"$.runid"
                }

}
```

For your reference, you can check.Supported parameters section: [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-glue.html).

**UPDATE:**
You need to add ResultPath in your task definitions like:

```
"First Glue Job":{
         "Type": "Task",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
         "Parameters": {
            "JobName": "GlueJob-Firstjob",
            "Arguments": {
                  "--runid":"$.runid"
                }
      },
       "ResultPath": "$.output"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have passed the Arguments as part of state machine with in Parameters section and it is taking value "$.runid" and it is not considering which I have passed as input during start execution of state machine.




I am passing like this in Input:{"runid":"Runid_10"} and expecting which has to consider value"Runid_10" .

Comment: Can you update your ASL/StepFunction definition with what all changes you have made for this? Makes it easier to figure out what's wrong

Comment: I have added Arguments Parameter inside step function in original question and executing state machine through aws console. Here it is saying characters are exceeded.

Comment: You will have to add ResultPath in your state definitions. otherwise the output that is coming from glue job will overwrite everything. and your next step will not find `$.runid`

Comment: Working fine, Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Adam : Sorry, dont know previously how to mark it as answered.

Comment: The argument name has to ends with .$ otherwise it's interpreted as a static value:
            "Arguments": {
                  "--runid.$":"$.runid"
             }

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to define a dynamic job name? I got a similar question here which got me stuck for ages, could you take a look please?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65722714/how-to-extract-part-of-the-string-from-execution-name-in-aws-step-function

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was trying to pass the output from previous lambda function as input into a Glue Job. All the flow was carried out in a Step Function.

Input for Glue Job obtained as Event from Previous Lambda Job.

[image]

I wanted to pass the "***sender***" value into glue job via Step Function. Therefore, I had to modify the API Parameters like below for adding arguments.

> **Strict Syntax** : "--sender.$" : "$.sender"

Make sure

- ***.$*** is followed at suffix in the **KEY**.
- ***.$*** is appended in prefix for **VALUE**.

[image]

In Code Snippet Section, Manually add the below snippet.

```
"ResultPath": "$.output"
```

Reference Screenshot for ResultPath.
[image]

Then in PySpark Glue Script, you can easily access the input parameters using the below snippet.

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['sender'])
print(args['sender'])
```

I hope the above answer helps your purpose.

Comment: Can you please add the documentation links as well. Also is it $. In prefix.  Link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

The input value 'runid' is passed as an event to the Lambda function inside your Step Function. To pass it from one Lambda function to the other, you can just return the event which will pass data from start to finish. That event contains your 'runid' argument.

Take a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-state-machine-data.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to write lambda function.

Comment: Lambda is a event driven based and please clarify me how we can pass from lambda to Glue job parameter.