# How to read the input state in a Step Function from a Glue Python job?

Tags: aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I have a step function that generates the following input for the next step:

```
{
  "name": "Done",
  "input": [
    {
      "success": "123"
    },
    {
      "failing": "123"
    }
  ],
  "inputDetails": {
    "truncated": false
  }
}
```

where the fields in `"input":[...]` are the output of other steps.

The step function for my job is

```
"Done": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "done",
        "Arguments": {
          "--job-output-states": "$$.input"
        }
      },
      "End": true,
      "Credentials": {
        "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/glue_test"
      }
    }
```

and the job code is

```
import sys
import boto3
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, [
    "job-output-states"
])

print(args)
```

The arguments passed to the Glue Python Job seem not parsed. How can I access from there to `"input":[...]`?

Comment: Please take a look at linked answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74939122/10671274). If I am not mistaken, your case is similar, and you only need to add .$ after --job-output-states in Arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me

```
"Done": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "done",
        "Arguments": {
          "--job-output-states.$": "States.JsonToString($)"
        }
      },
      "End": true,
      "Credentials": {
        "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/glue_test"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
   "Done": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "done",
        "Arguments": {
          "job-output-states.$": "$.input"
        }
      },
      "End": true,
      "Credentials": {
        "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/glue_test"
      }
    }
```

First thing, they key for job-output-states in our Arguments shouldn't need the "--". Step Functions integrates with the [startJobRun API for Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_StartJobRun.html#Glue-StartJobRun-request-Arguments), not with the CLI (which is where the -- syntax on the command line identifies an argument).

Second, in order for a key in your parameters to be replaced dynamically with a value from your input, you need to suffix the key with `.$`. When you do this, you are telling Step Functions that the value is variable (i.e., either a JSON Path reference or an Intrinsic Function). Otherwise, as with your other keys such as `JobName`, the value will be treated as a literal.

And third, you reference input with a single `$` in your (see docs for [Reference Paths](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-paths.html)). If you use `$$` that will reference the [Context Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html), which I don't think is what you want here.

Comment: I tried already with single `$` and also with `"--job-output-states": "States.JsonToString($.input)"` but seems not working. Btw the `--` I think is required to parse the arguments in the job

Comment: Please try with what I suggested and let me know if that works.

Comment: I also noticed that you are using Credentials, which will allow you to invoke this Glue API call using a different role from the main execution role for your state machine. Is that necessary in your case? As this is typically used for cross-account use cases.

Comment: When I read the logs of executed tasks I can see "$.input" does not get parsed.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have "job-output-states.$" in the key? If you don't have the .$ suffix, then Step Functions will just pass through the literal "$.input".